# How to combine legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm a beginner learner with R. I've been attempting to combine legends for so long and just can't seem to do it.

Data works fine and is accurate and plotted properly. Except colour and shape aren't combined in one legend but in separate legends.

Here's my code:

```
ggp1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Temperature, colour = "Africa", shape = "Africa")) +  
  geom_point(aes(y = y2, colour = "Asia", shape = "Asia")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y3, colour = "Europe", shape = "Europe")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y4, colour = "Australia", shape = "Australia"))
```

Edit:
Here's the data:

```
data <- data.frame(Year = df1$Year,
               Temperature = df1$Temperature.Africa,
               y2 = df1$Temperature.Asia,
               y3 = df1$Temperature.Europe,
               y4 = df1$Temperature.Australia)
```

[image: This is the output of the code]

Please help before I go crazy.

Comment: Your data will need to be reshaped. If you have a sample of data (or simulated numbers) to show the structure of the data we can help work out a solution.

Comment: Edited to add data

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve your desired result by assigning the same name to the `color` and `shape` legends or by removing both as I do in my code below using `labs`.

Using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) based on the `gapminder` dataset:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data
data <- gapminder |> 
  select(Year = year, continent, value = lifeExp) |> 
  group_by(Year, continent) |> 
  summarise(value = mean(value), .groups = "drop") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = continent, values_from = value) |> 
  select(Year, Temperature = 2, y2 = 3, y3 = 4, y4 = 5)
  
ggplot(data, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Temperature, colour = "Africa", shape = "Africa")) +  
  geom_point(aes(y = y2, colour = "Asia", shape = "Asia")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y3, colour = "Europe", shape = "Europe")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y4, colour = "Australia", shape = "Australia")) +
  labs(color = NULL, shape = NULL)
```

[image]